# Should questions where the OP reports they find the solution, but doesn't add the solution as answer be closed as too localized?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting-to-close

- [Insert images with Media](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3715/insert-images-with-media).
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1680/drupal-not-recognizing-updated-theme

In the first question, the OP updates the question one hour later the question was asked, to report they found the solution.
In the second question, the OP updates the question 8 minutes, to report the issue has been resolved, even if I am not sure it has been resolved in the correct way.

What should be done with such questions, in the case the OPs don't add the solution as answer after a week, and they have being asked to write what they found be the solution as answer? Should the questions be closed as too localized?

Comment: Not sure. Note that someone mentioned the other day that he could only accept his own answer 24h after he posted it, so we should at least give them a few days before doing anyting like that.

Comment: I am not referring to that timeframe. There is no rush to close the  question, which can be closed also a week later.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to mention that because I didn't knew about the 1-day wait thing before :)

Comment: @Bedir Yeah, it's easy to forget such restrictions, when you don't have them. `:-)` For example, depending on the reputation you have, you could not delete/close your own question, if not after two days you asked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> depending on the reputation you have, you could not delete/close your own question, if not after two days you asked it

This is not true. Question deletion restrictions have mostly to do with # of answers because you would be destroying other people's answer contributions.

> He could only accept his own answer 24h after he posted it

That is true, however, **there's no reason people can't self answer as soon as they have a solution**; accepts are more of a social convention than anything else.

One other note: if you have less than 100 reputation, you cannot self-answer for 8 hours. This is to prevent new users from abusing "answers" as comments or replies to others. We have a lot of new users who don't understand how our system works, so we have to protect them from themselves.

> In the second question, the OP updates the question 8 minutes, to report the issue has been resolved.

If the issue is resolved they should provide an answer, otherwise delete the question.